# my jquery code is not working code igniter

Tags: php, javascript, json, codeigniter, jquery

this is my javascript code ...i have written a function in my controller in which if false is return then i am echoing the 'userNo' other wise echo the json .. here is my javascript in which only else part is working not if part ... i have checked in firebug also .. i am getting a response "userNo" but dont know why it is not running the first part

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#hide').hide();
        $('#bill_no').blur(function(){

            if( $('#bill_no').val().length >= 3 )
                {
                  var bill_no = $('#bill_no').val();
                  getResult(bill_no); 
                }
            return false;
        })
        function getResult(billno){
            var baseurl = $('.hiddenUrl').val();
           $('.check').addClass('preloader');
            $.ajax({
                url : baseurl + 'returnFromCustomer_Controller/checkBillNo/' + billno,
                cache : false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function(response){
                     $('.check').removeClass('preloader');

                    if (response == "userNo") //this part is not working
                        alert("true");
                    else
                    $('.check').removeClass('userNo').addClass('userOk');
                    // $(".text").html(response.result);
                     $('#hide').show();
                     $(".text1").html(response.result1);
                     $(".text2").html(response.result2);
                     $(".text3").html(response.result3);

                }
            })
        }
    })


  </script>
```

my Controller

```
    function checkBillNo($billno)
{
    $this->load->model('returnModel');

    $query = $this->returnModel->checkBillNo($billno);

    //$billno =   $this->uri->segment(3);
    $billno_results  = $this->returnModel->sale($billno);

    if (!$billno_results){

            echo "userNo";


    }else{
        echo json_encode($billno_results);

    }




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *echo "userNO"*, try to use it:

```
echo json_encode(array('return' => 'userNo'));
```

... and in your JS, use this:

```
if (response.return == "userNo") { // ...
```

Comment: how can i hide the div in userNo part ....if i do this    $('#hide').hide(); ..then it didnt work .. but alerting the value successfully